What meaning do the の add here, and how?
I was wondering why these の appear in this sentence, and what they even do here.
空を見上げ願うの　君に射す光の
一つであれますように
The sentence is supposed to mean something along the lines of
"I look up at the sky and wish for the light shining on you,
so that we may be one" (At least that's what I think)
Thanks in advance for any help.

I make it: "Shall I wish, looking up at the sky, that one of those lights (meaning a star, presumably) could shine on you?" But the Japanese grammar takes a much different path to get at that meaning.

@KarlKnechtel This である is this. She herself wants to be like a star.

... Ah, of course.

The two の's are different.

The first の is a sentence-end particle used to add mild emphasis to the sentence. Roughly speaking, it's like "you see" or "you know" in English, but it doesn't always have to be translated. This type of の is primarily used by women and children.
The second の is a noun-linking or possessive particle. ～のひとつ is "one of the ～", so 光の一つ means "one of the lights". See this article.


空を見上げ願うの
君に射す光の 一つであれますように
I look up at the sky and wish,
To be (able to be) one of the lights shining on you

